# What is the difference between primaryColor and primarySwatch in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, one can apply a theme to the app using ThemeData class. But there two propeties of this class that confuses me: `primaryColor` and `primarySwatch`. What's the difference between these two properties and when to use one or the other? Thanks.

Comment: A color that has a small table of related colors called a "swatch".

Answer (score 203, accepted):

`primarySwatch` is *not* a `Color`. It's `MaterialColor`.
Which means it's different shades of a color a material app will use.

`primaryColor` is one of those shades. To be exact, `primaryColor` is normally equal to `primarySwatch[500]`.

It is usually better to define a `primarySwatch` instead of `primaryColor`. Because some material components may use a different shade of the `primaryColor` for things such as shadow, border, ...

Comment: what are the other shades?

Comment: more info here https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette

Comment: Any way to retrieve the primarySwatch value inside a widget to get a specific shade ? Because if not we're force to use only pre define one on the theme or hardcode them...

Comment: @jaumard You can't. `primarySwatch` is just a shortcut to set the other properties. If you need custom properties, you'll have to add fields to theme.

Comment: So what is the purpose of defining PrimarySwatch?

Comment: @Dennis primarySwatch is a shortcut. There are like 5 or 10 fields that are set from this variable.

Comment: @RémiRousselet still pretty vague, I mean what purpose will it solve if I will define `PrimarySwatch`?

Comment: @Dennis Not having to type all the fields yourself. Its pretty rare that you need to set them manually

Comment: I guess I get your point, so let's say you define a `PrimaryColor` value to `Colors.red[xxx]` but did not mention `PrimarySwatch` so some xyz MaterialWidget might use `Colors.red[yyy]` and thus defining `PrimarySwatch` solves the purpose?

Comment: Yeah. If you set only `PrimaryColor` you may fall into weird cases where some widgets aren't using that color because they use a different `Theme` field.

Comment: @RémiRousselet could you list what are those 5-10 fields? I have a color palette sent from my designer and I am not sure I can match it to a swatch (a Material Color) so I want to fill all the fields and not get caught by surprise if any Widgets are expecting a color that I didn't provide (but `primarySwatch` would have)

Comment: @mFeinstein Since that requires a lot more explanation than can be given in a comment, I have added an answer for you below (perhaps a bit late for your project, but hopefully it will help you in the future and anyone else who comes along)

Answer (score 23):

The following is taking from my perusal of theme_data.dart:

`primarySwatch` defaults to `Colors.blue` and sets the following fields (including `primaryColor`) to various shades of the `MaterialColor` input depending on whether the theme `brightness` is light or dark (default is light):

### Light Themes

```dart
// The default shade for the color is used
primaryColor = primarySwatch; // [500] for normal colors and [200] for accent colors
```

```dart
primaryColorLight = primarySwatch[100];
```

```dart
primaryColorDark = primarySwatch[700];
```

```dart
// This can be overridden by setting accentColor (below) manually
toggleableActiveColor = primarySwatch[600];
```

```dart
accentColor = primarySwatch[500];
```

```dart
secondaryHeaderColor = primarySwatch[50];
```

```dart
textSelectionColor = primarySwatch[200];
```

```dart
textSelectionHandleColor = primarySwatch[300]
```

```dart
backgroundColor = primarySwatch[200];
```

*buttonColor is set to its default (grey[300])

### Dark Themes

```dart
buttonColor = primarySwatch[600];
```

*The remaining fields listed above for light themes are set to their dark defaults (various shades of tealAccent, grey or black)

### All Themes (light or dark)

```dart
// Brightness.dark/light is estimated based on the default shade for the color
// This also sets the bool primaryIsDark
primaryColorBrightness = estimateBrightnessForColor(primarySwatch);
```

```dart
// This generates the modern simplified set of theme colors flutter recommends
// using when theming Widgets based on the theme. Set it manually if you need
// more control over individual colors
colorScheme = ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
      primarySwatch: primarySwatch, // as above
      primaryColorDark: primaryColorDark, // as above
      accentColor: accentColor, // as above
      cardColor: cardColor, // default based on theme brightness, can be set manually
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor, // as above
      errorColor: errorColor, // default (Colors.red[700]), can be set manually
      brightness: brightness, // default (Brightness.light), can be set manually
    );
```

As mentioned in the accepted answer, only setting `primaryColor` could leave Widgets open to selecting some other default color (various shades of blue) based on one of the other fields above if they are not also set individually, so `primarySwatch` is a convenient shorthand for simple themes.

In general, however, the colorScheme field is most important as per modern conventions you should be using `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.<Color>` (though it may not work everywhere yet depending on when you read this).

So, if you need more control over individual theme colors, you could either make do with setting the fields used in `ColorScheme.fromSwatch`, or just set the `primarySwatch` (for backwards compatibility of Flutter Widgets that have not yet been migrated), and then set the `colorScheme` manually for extra control. [See also this document for more information…](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kzIOQN4QYfVsc5lMZgy_A-FWGXBAJBMySGqZqsJytcE/edit#heading=h.pub7jnop54q0)

Comment: Definitely this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

**Swatch** is a category. **Color** is a range in that category although not limited to it. Based on swatch colour you specify flutter can picks a background and a foreground  colour it feels suitable for a component.

**tldr**;

Its important to understand the difference b/w a swatch and a color. **A swatch is a category of colour**. Its of type `MaterialColor`  Material has below listed swatches plus white. *(ignore 50)*

[image: Various Swatches]

*.*

Each swatch has various ranges. **An individual in a swatch/range is a colour** although you aren't restricted by it. You can specify any valid colour code even though it's not inside a swatch range.

[image]

*.*

Based on swatch colour you specify flutter can picks a background and a foreground  colour it feels suitable for a component.

*.*

Here is a list of all swatches and their colours. Screenshot taken from https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#tools-for-picking-colors

[image: Various Swatches]

Comment: Thanks for all the visualisations.

Answer (score 5):

primarySwatch is [MaterialColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialColor-class.html).

```
/// Defines a single color as well a color swatch with ten shades of the color.
///
/// The color's shades are referred to by index. The greater the index, the
/// darker the color. There are 10 valid indices: 50, 100, 200, ..., 900.
/// The value of this color should the same the value of index 500 and [shade500].     
/// hex_value1 = 0xFFAAD401; hex_value2 = 0xFFAAD403; ...
MaterialColor myGreen = const MaterialColor(0xFFAAD400,
      const {
        50 : const Color(hex_value1),
        100 : const Color(hex_value2),
        200 : const Color(hex_value3),
        300 : const Color(hex_value4),
        400 : const Color(hex_value5),
        500 : const Color(hex_value6),
        600 : const Color(hex_value7),
        700 : const Color(hex_value8),
        800 : const Color(hex_value9),
        900 : const Color(hex_value10)});
// use MaterialColor: myGreen.shade100,myGreen.shade500 ...
myGreen.shade50 // Color === 0xFFAAD401
```