# How to change Colors.orage ro Colors.orage[800] on Theme?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I need to change my entire application theme. I addded this in my main method. Is it best way to change entire application theme or is that another way? Please tell me.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange
      ),
```

**I need to change into Colors.orange[800]. I added this color code but not working error is coming.**

Comment: which error message is displayed to you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`primarySwatch` excepts a `MaterialColor`, `Colors.orange[800]` is a `Color`.

To solve the issue you can set the `primaryColor` to `Colors.orange[800]` [see the difference between primarySwatch and primaryColor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50214259/4465386).

Or alternately create a custom `MaterialColor` object for the primarySwatch, like this:

```
MaterialColor materialOrange = MaterialColor(
    0xFFEF6C00, // this is the primary color, it is set to the value of orange[800]
    <int, Color>{
       50: Color(0xFFFFF3E0),
      100: Color(0xFFFFE0B2),
      200: Color(0xFFFFCC80),
      300: Color(0xFFFFB74D),
      400: Color(0xFFFFA726),
      500: Color(0xFFF57C00),
      600: Color(0xFFF57C00),
      700: Color(0xFFF57C00),
      800: Color(0xFFEF6C00),
      900: Color(0xFFE65100),
    },
  );
```

Comment: ilike this? How to set 800? ```MaterialColor materialOrange = MaterialColor(
      0xFFEF6C00,
      <int, Color>{
        50: Color(0xFFFFF3E0),
        100: Color(0xFFFFE0B2),
        200: Color(0xFFFFCC80),
        300: Color(0xFFFFB74D),
        400: Color(0xFFFFA726),
        500: Color(0xFFF57C00),
        600: Color(0xFFF57C00),
        700: Color(0xFFF57C00),
        800: Color(0xFFEF6C00),
        900: Color(0xFFE65100),
      },
    );
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: materialOrange
      ),```

Comment: How to set 800?

Comment: @BhanukaIsuru the code you wrote is correct. If it doesn't work, it could be that a widget is taking the `materialOrange[500]`, so you can set it to `Color(0xFFEF6C00)` or even have all of the values in the map set to `Color(0xFFEF6C00)`