# Reuse custom color in ThemeData

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class for declaring custom colors.

```
class CustomColors {
static const Color myCustomBlack = const Color(0x8A000000);
}
```

My question is: Why I can not use them in Theme data as follows?

```
ThemeData(primarySwatch : CustomColors.myCustomBlack)
```

Comment: error message?? Is this useful? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50214259/469335

Comment: Yes, That makes sens. I was setting a Color to primarySwatch which isn't a color. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`primarySwatch` isn't a normal `Color`, it is a `MaterialColor`, so you can't assign any `Color` to it. And a `MaterialColor` is the one which has shades like `100`, `200`, ... `900`.

For example:

`Colors.blue` is a `MaterialColor` as you can use shades like `Colors.blue[100]` and `Colors.black` isn't a `MaterialColor`, you get error on using `Colors.black[100]`.