# PrimarySwatch, accentColor and canvasColor

Tags: flutter

Can someone briefly explain to me where are all the three themes(Primary Swatch, accent Color and canvas Color) used in flutter? 
I find extensive use of these themes but am very confused which widgets use which theme?

Comment: Your question is really one of Material Design. Yes, people are using them in Flutter but that's not because of anything in Flutter. I'd suggest researching themes and swatches in Material Design to get a better idea of why people are making the color choices you're seeing.

Comment: This might also help. To get a List of all the primary material color swatches, see what comes up when you type "Colors.primaries." (don't forget the last . if it does nothing after you type the 's')

Comment: To me this question is unsolvable. Those Colors are not themes but part of a theme and which component uses what accent in a specific part is not really defined. Nor can it be summarized generally. But as others said, reading Material Design Guidelines will get you a better understanding for the concepts.

Answer (score 4):

**primarySwatch**: is a main color of app for example it change the color of appbar

**accentColor**: or secondary color is The foreground color for widgets for example floatingActionButton

**canvasColor**: and this can change the color of scaffold widget

Comment: Isn't `scaffoldBackgroundColor` the color of the scaffold widget?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to learn Material Design to understand them. Check [this](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html).

**primarySwatch** is a MaterialColor, not a color. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50214259/5851439).

**accentColor** is a secondary color. It might be used for active tab, focused input texts, checked boxes etc.

**canvasColor** is the default color of MaterialType.canvas Material. [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/canvasColor.html).