# The argument type 'Color' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MaterialColor?

Tags: flutter, dart

**How can I use RGBO in primarySwatch**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

primarySwatch is not a Color. It's MaterialColor. Which means it's a the different shades of a color a material app will use. Default color is blue.
For more read articles
https://dev.to/rohanjsh/custom-swatch-for-material-app-theme-primaryswatch-3kic

[What is the difference between primaryColor and primarySwatch in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50212484/what-is-the-difference-between-primarycolor-and-primaryswatch-in-flutter)